# How to change child component style with Emulated encapsulation in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, css, angular6

How do I update certain child component css from parent without changing the encapsulation view ?

Here is sample [demo](https://angular-nbhhwp.stackblitz.io/)

**app.component.ts**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 class='test'>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`.test { font-family: Lato;color:red; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

**app.component.css**

```
:host ::ng-deep .test{
  color:green;
}

p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
```

I can see in chrome toolbar that its trying to override the style however child component still display color:red.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close missing one thing on your CSS.

```
:host ::ng-deep hello .test{
  color:green;
}
```

where `hello` is the component selector.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74ajje

Comment: Yupp, it's a [selector specifity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) issue. could also add `!important` to the override class.

Comment: Please make every effort you can to avoid `!important`, It's almost entirely avoidable in an encapsulated framework like Angular.

Comment: can I use ng-deep as global for all components ? I do not want to hard code component name...this class can be used in multiple places

Comment: @Zeus if you want a css selector that is available through all your app, the best place to put it would be on `styles.css` provided you are using `angular-cli` of course.

Comment: :host ::ng-deep .test{
  color:green;
}
putting this in styles,css does not work

Comment: @Zeus, for `styles.css` you can't use any of those selectors, it would be just a normal css. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uj5lo

Comment: I see so the !important is the key here, without that it will not work right ?

Comment: @Zeus, Depends since in this case we want to override what's defined in `hello` component.

Comment: if !important is applied inside the child component color , then can we override it ?

Comment: @Zeus, yep sure, I just edited the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uj5lo

Comment: So now its showing the color red, not green. Basically if child has !important then we can't override it. Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The `:host` pseudo-selector targets the host *element* of your component (e.g. `<app-hello>`, an element not available in its own markup). It's as simple as it sounds.

`::ng-deep` is a little different. When Angular compiles component styles, this selector will cause the style to trickle down through all child components as part of their own encapsulated context.

What you're saying with `:host ::ng-deep .test {` is "target descendants of the host element `[_nghost-c1]` and all elements that are children of the host element with class="test".

The rule `.test {`, encapsulated in this component, says "target every element in this component (compiled to `[_ngcontent-c1]`) with class="test".

Since the `h1` is a descendant of the host but a direct member of the component, the latter is a more specific rule, and wins the CSS battle.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.